# Can't remove dashes (-) from string

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

The following function strips some words into an array, adjusts whitespaces and does something else I need. I also need to remove dashes, as I write them as words too. But this function doesn't remove dashes. What's wrong?

```
function stripwords($string) 
{ 
  // build pattern once 
  static $pattern = null; 
  if ($pattern === null) { 
    // pull words to remove from somewhere 
    $words = array('alpha', 'beta', '-');  
    // escape special characters 
    foreach ($words as &$word) { 
      $word = preg_quote($word, '#'); 
    } 
    // combine to regex 
    $pattern = '#\b(' . join('|', $words) . ')\b\s*#iS'; 
  } 

  $print = preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);
  list($firstpart)=explode('+', $print);
  return $firstpart;

}
```

Comment: What does `$pattern` look like?

Comment: It's hypen, not a dash. Dash is: —

Comment: Can you give an example that doesn’t work as expected?

Comment: @Buddy "ES80 -" is not a dash? anyway i tried with hypen and dash both and it doesn't remove...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, the problem is the `\b` which designates a word boundary. If you have a space before or after the hyphen, it won't remove it as in " - ", the word boundary doesn't apply.

From http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html:

> There are three different positions
>   that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> 1. Before the first character in the
>      string, if the first character is a
>      word character.
> 2. After the last
>      character in the string, if the last
>      character is a word character.
> 3. Between
>      two characters in the string, where
>      one is a word character and the other
>      is not a word character.
>
> A "word character" is a character that can be used to form words.

**A simple solution:**

By adding `\s` along with `\b` to your pattern and using a positive look-behind and a positive look-ahead, you should be able to solve your problem.

```
$pattern = '#(?<=\b|\s|\A)(' . join('|', $words) . ')(?=\b|\s|\Z)\s*#iS';
```

Comment: and how to do with whitespaces and composite words? that is... i need that "alpha" is stripped out when is a single word only ... and not alpha in alphabeta (composite word, example)

Comment: @smepie - I've updated the regular expression above to use a positive look-ahead and a positive look-behind to look for the word boundary and space. It's also not perfect as in it won't remove a dash if it's the last character or if a word starts or ends with dash.

Comment: with your pattern "CANON DIGITAL" becomes CNONgitl and SAMSUNG -> SMSUNG so maybe that means it conflicts with other words into the array...

Comment: @smepie - I tried "CANON DIGITAL" and "SAMSUNG" right not and they worked great. You must have something else stripping the letter "A".

Comment: well, explain better: every word i write into the array, it has to remove. ok... but it has to remove A only when A is alone. Is it clear now?

Comment: @smepie - Sure. But when I tried it using the code above and by adding "a" to the list of "words" to remove, "CANON" is "CANON", not "CNON". See for yourself [http://codepad.viper-7.com/UTv8Qb](http://codepad.viper-7.com/UTv8Qb).

Comment: sorry...it was the early version, now it seems to work but strange behaviour: the word "nero" is one of the words into the array, now it strips dashes but not "nero"....how is it possible?

Comment: ES80 - NERO ... it strips - but not NERO

Comment: @smepie - I've updated the pattern again. I think this one should solve all of your problems. It also uses `\A` and `\Z` to take care of dashes that start or end the string too.

Comment: OK we are near the solution :-) but for "alpha-beta" it has not to strip anything if i don't write alpha-beta exactly into the array...

Comment: @smepie - In that case, you'll have to do away with the `\b` as there is a word boundary in "alpha-beta" where the hyphen is. Use `$pattern = '#(?<=\s|\A)(' . join('|', $words) . ')(?=\s|\Z)\s*#iS';`.

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in your regex pattern are you looking for dashes. Why not just do

```
$string = str_replace('-', '', $string);
```

after you do your regex stuff?