# Java Remove dash from string

Tags: android, string, replace

it's not a duplicate of [Remove dash from a phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717421/remove-dash-from-a-phone-number)
maybe solution is here but i don't understand [Can't remove dashes (-) from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585249/cant-remove-dashes-from-string)

I have to remove al - (dash) from a String, alzo i have to remove " -" and "- " (all space near the dash)
This don't work (do nothing)

```
toclean.replaceAll("[\\s\\-()]", "");
        toclean.replaceAll("[\\s\\- ()]", "");
        toclean.replaceAll("[\\s\\ -()]", "");
```

idea?

Comment: Can you provide an example, your expected result, and the actual result for each of those?

Comment: first problem solved with toclean= toclean.replaceAll("[\\s\\-()]", "");

Comment: You're correct that you're missing assignment. I don't know how I didn't catch that. Note, however, that that regex will still remove all whitespace, even if it's not next to a hyphen. I don't know whether that fits your requirements or not.

Comment: Try something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555700/regex-strip-spaces-hyphen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want all spaces around the dash, whereas the regexes you've tried will remove all whitespace, dashes, and parentheses from your string. A regex to remove hyphens and the spaces around them would be:

```
"[ ]?-[ ]?"
```

If you want to remove any whitespace, you could use \s:

```
"\\s?-\\s?"
```

This will only remove the nearest whitespace before and after any hyphens (so, if you have two spaces before, it will only remove one).

Comment: in my string i have to (only) remove dash and nearest whitespace. not other symbols

Comment: Updated my answer. The regex will now remove hyphens and the nearest whitespace before and after, if any exists (previously, it would match all whitespace before and after).